# How to place results of mysql row into SEPERATE variables

Tags: php, mysql, row

Hello I have this code up to now

```
#issue query  
$query1 = "SELECT ITEM_NAME FROM items_to_buy
ORDER BY ITEM_NAME ASC";


$result1 = mysql_query ($query1)
or die ("Cannot execute query");        

$itemnamesdata = array();     

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) 
{
$itemnamesdata[] = $row[0];       
} 

for ($n = 0; $n < count($itemnamesdata); $n++) 

{
$Line = each ($itemnamesdata);

print ("$Line[value].<p>\n");      

}           

  mysql_free_result ($result);
```

And it works and gives me all the items in the column : item_name
and prints them like so :

```
Widescreen VA
460W PSU
Router
DSLR Body
Winter Jacket
Smartphone
17-50MM F/2.8 LENS
Colormeter
```

Now how do I place each results into it's own unique variable?

I want to be able to call them separately like so:

```
$value1 = Widescreen VA
$value2 = 460W PSU
$value3 = Router
$value4 = DSLR Body
$value5 = Winter Jacket
$value6 = Smartphone
$value7 = 17-50MM F/2.8 LENS
$value8 = Colormeter
```

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: You can use dynamyc variable name : `${'value'.$increment}`

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you have numbered variables like this, then using an array is naturally more appropriate

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli).

Comment: Why two loop ? Put `$Line = each ($itemnamesdata);`

`print ("$Line[value].<p>\n"); ` in your while ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the loop itself you can do this:

```
$arr = array();
for ($n = 0; $n < count($itemnamesdata); $n++){
  $Line = each ($itemnamesdata);

  print ("$Line[value].<p>\n"); 
  $arr['var_' . $n] = $Line['value'];
}  

extract($arr);
```

Comment: so how do I print just value 4 for example?

Comment: echo $var_3;
Thats it.

Answer (score 1):

You would just be able to

```
echo $itemnamesdata[0];
echo $itemnamesdata[1]; // etc
```

Comment: This gives me each item 8 times

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamyc variable name : `${'value'.$increment}`

Example :

```
$increment = 5;

${'value'.$increment} = 'a';

echo $value5;

//echo a
```

Comment: Correct but also a bad idea.